# How to combine files in subdirectories in macOS

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders named as dates.

```
1-1-2013, 1-1-2014, 1-1-2015, ...
```

I want to combine all the files in subfolders that match the same year into a new folder named after the year. So in this example, all the folders ending in the year 2013 (1-1-2013) would go into a folder named "2013" and so on.

How do I accomplish this with Automator?

Comment: Have you tried writing the script on your own? Did you run into any difficulty with it? There are a lot of wonderful resources on the Internet you can use to learn to help you accomplish it on your own.

Comment: Your question has contradicting statements! You first say "_I want to combine all the files in subfolders that match the same year into a new folder named after the year._", and then you say "_So in this example, all the folders ending in the year 2013 (1-1-2013) would go into a folder named "2013" and so on._". So which is it!? Do you want to move the _folders_ .e.g. **1-1-2013** into a _folder_ named **2013**, **or** do you want to move the _files_ in _folder_ **1-1-2013** into a _folder_ named **2013**!?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it would be use the Terminal, and write command as follows:

```
mkdir 2013
```

This create a folder named 2013 after the year.

```
mv *-2013/* 2013
```

This moves all the files from the folders those names end with "-2013" into the folder named 2013.

If you have a large number of years to do this for, consider using a simple bash script with a `for` loop - something like this:

```
for year in {2000..2020} 
do
  mkdir $year
  mv *-$year/* $year 
done
```

Comment: The OP has has contradicting statements! First said is "_I want to combine all the files in subfolders that match the same year into a new folder named after the year._", and then said "_So in this example, all the folders ending in the year 2013 (1-1-2013) would go into a folder named "2013" and so on._". So depending on what is actually wanted, `*-$year/*` may need to be changed to: `*-$year`